# Merge more than 2 csv files in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can I merge more than 2 files that e.g. look like these

first csv file:

```
email,joe,@gmail.com
email,doe,@hotmail.com
name,emilly,doe
name,jenny,van
year,talia,19
year,kevin,20
```

second csv file:

```
email,joe,mr
email,doe,mrs
name,jenny,gogh
year,talia,97
```

I would like to merge these files to look like this:

```
email,joe,@gmail.com,mr
email,doe,@hotmail.com,mrs
name,emilly,doe,nan
name,jenny,van,gogh
year,talia,19,97
year,kevin,20,nan
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[0, 1], how='outer') \
  .to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False, na_rep='nan')

# Content of file:
email,joe,@gmail.com,mr
email,doe,@hotmail.com,mrs
name,emilly,doe,nan
name,jenny,van,gogh
year,talia,19,97
year,kevin,20,nan
```

**Update**

> How to merge more than 2 csv files? Can I use merge() for 3 csv files too?

I split your second file into 2 parts:

```
# data1.csv
email,joe,@gmail.com
email,doe,@hotmail.com
name,emilly,doe
name,jenny,van
year,talia,19
year,kevin,20

# data2.csv
email,joe,mr
email,doe,mrs

# data3.csv
name,jenny,gogh
year,talia,97
```

Use `reduce` from `functools` module:

```
filenames = ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fn, header=None ) for fn in filenames]
df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[0, 1], how='outer'), dfs)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False, na_rep='nan')
```

Output:

```
email,joe,@gmail.com,mr,nan
email,doe,@hotmail.com,mrs,nan
name,emilly,doe,nan,nan
name,jenny,van,nan,gogh
year,talia,19,nan,97
year,kevin,20,nan,nan
```

Comment: How to merge more than 2 csv files? Can I use merge() for 3 csv files too?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please? Look carefully the output.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left or default inner join:

```
#convert files to DataFrames, if no header added header=None
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, header=None)

#left join by first 2 columns
df = df1.merge(df2, on=[0,1], how='left')
print (df)
       0       1           2_x   2_y
0  email     joe    @gmail.com    mr
1  email     doe  @hotmail.com   mrs
2   name  emilly           doe   NaN
3   name   jenny           van  gogh
4   year   talia            19    97
5   year   kevin            20   NaN
```

If need values skipped:

```
#inner join by first 2 columns
df = df1.merge(df2, on=[0,1])
print (df)
       0      1           2_x   2_y
0  email    joe    @gmail.com    mr
1  email    doe  @hotmail.com   mrs
2   name  jenny           van  gogh
3   year  talia            19    97

#write to file
df.to_csv(file3, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: The lines that don't exist on the second file would be skipped. E.g. the line `name,emilly,doe,nan` wouldn't be written on the merged file

Comment: @iamgroot - Sorry, I am confused, output is different like in question what need? Also why is merged `year,talia,19` with `gender,talia,97` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. Please have a look on my question again, i have edited the code.

Comment: @iamgroot - added to my answer.